Annoying Chrome browser predictive text
Today I discovered that the Chrome browser has a new predictive text feature that's highly annoying. When I type in a field it displays a list of possible word completions. I might want to explore this option, but for now I want to turn it off. I can't anything in the settings or anything online about it. How to turn it off? I'm having a hard time even typing this post.

